# How to do a hard reset?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, contacts, reset, lumia-640-xl

I have a Lumia 640XL and I updated it two nights ago to Windows 10. Now, along with other things, I can't add contacts to the People app, and it just shuts down every time I click on the plus button to do so. I've tried updating it through the store, I've tried shutting the phone off and back on. Nothing has worked. All my text messages were gone after the update to Win 10, so I've lost those numbers for good anyway. But I'd like to be able to add contacts when people do text me! I'm guessing the only option is a hard reset, but I don't know how to go about doing that. Can anyone tell me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1**

1. Press and hold the <kbd>volume down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the
   same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds).
2. When you feel the vibration, release the buttons, and then
   immediately press and hold the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button until you see a
   large exclamation mark.
3. Once the exclamation mark appears, press the following four buttons
   in this order: <kbd>volume up</kbd>, <kbd>volume down</kbd>, <kbd>Power</kbd>, <kbd>volume down</kbd>.
4. Your phone should now reset and restart itself.
5. It might take a while for the reset to finish.

**Method 2:**

1. Go to Settings->About page.
2. Press *Reset the phone* button.

**Reference :**

For further reference see these webpages,

1. [Soft and Hard reset - Answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d)
2. [Reset my phone - Windows 10 mobile - Microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/reset-my-phone)
3. [Reset my phone - WP8.1 - Microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10666/windows-phone-reset-my-phone)

Comment: @Kelvinelove The **officcial Microsoft site says it as hard reset.** See the reference links I have provided in the answer itself. I am also adding it here. Ref : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d

Answer (score 2):

I would advise that you try a **soft reset** before sacrificing your data and time in doing a hard reset. Soft resets usually resolve most application and account problems. 
This method will not remove anything at all from your phone and is completely safe to attempt in any problem situation, so it's best to try it out first, before proceeding with a hard reset if the problem proves to be stubborn.

#### Soft Reset

Whilst your phone is on:

> Press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds). Ignore the "slide down to power off" screen.

Soft resetting a phone usually resolve application problems. However, if the problem is not resolved, you can then perform a Hard Reset:

#### Hard Reset

> Press and hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds). Ignore the `slide down to power off` screen.
>   When you feel the vibration, release the buttons, and then immediately press and hold the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button until you see a large exclamation mark.
>
> Once the exclamation mark appears, press the following four buttons in this order: <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>,<kbd>Power</kbd> and <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>. 
>   Your phone should now reset and restart itself. It might take a while for the reset to finish. You should see gears/cogs turning on the display, to signify the process. It might take a while to finish.

You can check further instructions on **[How to perform soft and hard resets](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d)** in the [linked article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d)