# Imie give data its creating problem

Tags: contacts, lumia-630

I buy nokia lumia 630 from some one and he knows the imie of phone and he stole all my contacts and starting blackmail me...i am in great trouble please sort out this issue so he can't find any info from that imie...or do anything else.. i am near to die because of that

Comment: Please clarify your question. Knowing your phone's IMEI number shouldn't give someone access to your contacts or other personal information. What exactly happened and how do you know your contacts have been stolen? Has your Microsoft account been compromised? Also, if you're being blackmailed, then you should probably contact the authorities.

Answer (score 0):

> please sort out this issue so he can't find any info from that imie

As Indrek pointed out already no one can steal data by just knowing the IMEI number of a mobile.

> I buy nokia lumia 630 from some one and he knows the imie of phone and
>   he stole all my contacts

There is a possiblity that the mobile phone could be linked to his Microsoft account. In that case do the following

- Backup contacts to SD card either using [Transfer My data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/transfer-my-data/9wzdncrfj3dr) or [contacts+messages backup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/contacts-message-backup/9nblgggz57gm).
- Delete all contacts from your phone.
- Reset your phone (You can see [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13338/18061) for more information on .[How to Reset your Windows phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13338/18061)).
- Restore all contacts from SD card.

Also make your Microsoft account password is strong and if possible change it.